# How to make FlipView with slow moving headers? UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, microsoft-metro, win-universal-app

How to make a view like on the screenshot? If you drag it to the next item, header moves too, but slower than content, and changes color.

[image: View with headers; example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FlipView` does not provides property to set headers. As @Archana said, you can use [Pivot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pivot.aspx). There is an official sample from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/XamlPivot) that uses the `Pivot`. This sample shows how to use a `Pivot` control in your UWP application.

You can set the `Header` in the `PivotItem`. The header and item are associated, so the item will change immediately when the header changes. On the contrary, the header will change immediately when the item changes. As I known, there is no method to delay the appearance of the header.

You can change the color of text in selected header. You can add the `TextBlock` to the content of `PivotItem.Header`. And you can add the `SelectionChanged` event in `Pivot`.

For example:

```
<Pivot Name="MyPivot" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
    <PivotItem>
        <PivotItem.Header>
            <TextBlock  Foreground="White" Text="Hello" />
        </PivotItem.Header>
        <TextBlock>When headers are in 'Dynamic' mode, hovering a mouse over the pivot headers will show mouse flippers for easy tab switching
        </TextBlock>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem>
        <PivotItem.Header>
            <TextBlock  Foreground="White" Text="Keyboard Support" />
        </PivotItem.Header>
        <TextBlock>
        <Run>Pivot now supports the following keyboard behaviors</Run><LineBreak />
        <Run> * While the HeaderPanel is focused:</Run><LineBreak />
        <Run> * * Left, Right, Ctrl+PgUp, Ctrl+PgDown: Changes the currently selected PivotItem</Run><LineBreak />
        <Run> * * Down: Sets focus in the content area</Run><LineBreak />
        <Run> * While the Content area is focused:</Run><LineBreak />
        <Run> * * Ctrl+PgUp, Ctrl+PgDown: Changes the currently selected PivotItem</Run>
        </TextBlock>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

In code behind:

```
private void MyPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (PivotItem pivotItem in MyPivot.Items)
    {
        if (pivotItem == MyPivot.Items[MyPivot.SelectedIndex])
        {
            ((TextBlock)pivotItem.Header).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        }
        else
        {
            ((TextBlock)pivotItem.Header).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(115, 123, 120, 130));
        }
    }
}
```